# Python: Is there a faster way than using autocorrect for spell correction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spell-checking, autocorrect

I am doing sentiment analysis and have `train` and `test` csv files with a `train` dataframe (created after reading the csv files) which has columns `text` and `sentiment`.

Tried in google-colab:

```
!pip install autocorrect
from autocorrect import spell 
train['text'] = [' '.join([spell(i) for i in x.split()]) for x in train['text']]
```

But it's taking forever to come to a halt. Is there a better way to auto-correct the pandas column? How to do it?

P.S.: the dataset is large enough, having around 5000 rows and each `train['text']` value has around 300 words and is of type `str`. I have **not** broken the `train['text']` into sentences.

Comment: @tester any options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some sample data:

```
from typing import List
from autocorrect import spell
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

data_train: List[str] = fetch_20newsgroups(
    subset='train',
    categories=['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.space'],
    shuffle=True,
    random_state=444
).data

df = pd.DataFrame({"train": data_train})
```

Corpus size:

```
>>> df.shape
(2034, 1)
```

Mean length of document in characters:

```
>>> df["train"].str.len().mean()
1956.4896755162242
```

First observation: `spell()` (I've never used `autocorrect`) is *reaallly* slow. It takes 7.77s just on *one document*!

```
>>> first_doc = df.iat[0, 0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
>>> len(first_doc.split())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
547
>>> first_doc[:100]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
'From: dbm0000@tm0006.lerc.nasa.gov (David B. Mckissock)\nSubject: Gibbons Outlines SSF Redesign Guida'
>>> %time " ".join((spell(i) for i in first_doc.split()))                                                                                                                                                                                                    
CPU times: user 7.77 s, sys: 159 ms, total: 7.93 s
Wall time: 7.93 s
```

So that function, rather than choosing between a vectorized Pandas method or `.apply()`, is probably your bottleneck.  A back of the envelope calculation, given that this document is roughly 1/3 as long as the average, has your total, non-parallelized calculation time at 7.93 * 3 * 2034 == 48,388 seconds.  Not pretty.

To that end, **consider parallelization**.  This is a highly parallelization task: apply a CPU-bound, simple callable across a collection of documents.  [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) has an easy API for this.  At this point, you can take the data structure out of Pandas and into something lightweight, such as a list or tuple.

Example:

```
>>> corpus = df["train"].tolist()  # or just data_train from above...                                                                                                                                                                                        
>>> import concurrent.futures                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> os.cpu_count()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
24
>>> with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
...     corrected = executor.map(lambda doc: " ".join((spell(i) for i in doc)), corpus)
```

Comment: I'll try that and update if that works on colaboratory...and surely will accept accordingly. And is it considered a good practice for conferring to lightweight structures (in terms of memory) ?

Comment: *converting to list or tuple.

Comment: Hi, my god!! what CPU configuration you have ??? I mean in google collab and my cpu `os.cpu_count` returns `2`. Checked the properties it says `AMD PRO A6-9500 R5 2C + 6G` ? So that means I can't have more than 2 compute cores, right ?  Is there a way to do it online somewhere as of now ?

Comment: Haven't used Google Colab, but that was from a [Mac Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Pro) @Rex5.  However, AWS, Azure, and the others all offer VMs that you can use on a short term basis with twice or three times than many core